# Does FileUpload control affect a GridView's output?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

First, the fileupload control is NOT in the gridview.

I have a WORKING aspx page that allows users to choose criteria from ListBoxes. The criteria are sent to query a back-end SQL server database that returns a resultset that is used to populate the gridview. This page is WORKING and has been used thousands of times.

```
<asp:GridView ID="CCGridView" runat="server" Visible="true" >
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="True" BorderColor="#DDDDDD"></HeaderStyle>
  <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="#DDDDDD" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I simply added a fileupload control to the page so users could add their own criteria.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" Width="250" MaxLength="150" runat="server" />
```

In the DB, I am capturing the resulting query and I see that it is correct and returns results.

The problem is this: when I use the fileupload control and upload a file, the grid's only output is a header with the word "output" and one blank cell.

Again, I am capturing the query, including the fileupload's part and I see clearly in the DB that the query is working correctly; when I run the captured query, it returns results exactly as I expect.

If I do NOT use the fileupload control, the grid populates normally, as it did before I added the fileupload control.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Seth

Comment: Does your file upload perform a postback? in that case you are failing to populate your GridView on PageLoad(). Can you attach you code behind?

Comment: Hi Chris, I am populating the gridview in code behind in a button click event, like I've done many times before:`connection.Open();`
`SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();`
`if (reader.HasRows)`
`{`
`readerHasRows = true;`
`DataTable dt = new DataTable();`
`dt.Load(reader);`
`int i = dt.Rows.Count;`
`
`ContactCountsGridView.DataSource = dt;`
`ContactCountsGridView.DataBind();`
`ContactCountsGridView.Visible = true;`
`}`
`else`
`ContactCountsGridView.Visible = false;`
`
`reader.Close();`
`connection.Close();`

Comment: Is the button click event associated with the file upload?